# how to access Django form fields through HTML

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have created models.py, forms.py, views.py & registeration.html.
At the moment in registeration.html I am directly importing the django form like `{{reg_form.as_p}}`, I can also do it in following two ways: `{{ form.as_table }}` or `{{ form.as_ul }}`. what I want is to have a real control over the fields to be displayed. Meaning to say some fields may be tabular, some may be list etc with specific css. 
What I tried in html to access the field is mentioned below:

```
id={{form.id_FullName}} name={{form.FullName}}
```

In models.py I have:

```
FullName = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

The above way didnt work, I want some way to access the django fields in HTML.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241379/accessing-individual-form-fields-in-django-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `name` and pass the `modelname` ,
Change  like this,

```
<input type="text" id="id_FullName" value=""  name="FullName" />.
```

and submit your form.

**Example , lets say signup form :**

**forms.py,**

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.CharField(label='email', max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(label='password', max_length=100)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py,**

```
def signup(request):
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
        if not form.is_valid():
            print form.errors
            return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(email=email,
                                                password=password,
                                                     )
            new_user.is_active = True
            new_user.save()
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^signup', views.signup, name='signup'),
```

Finally in your templates ie **signup.html**,

```
<form action="." method="post"> {% csrf_token %}     

              <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="inputUsernameEmail" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
              </div>

              <input type="submit" name="Sign up" value="Sign up" id="Sign_up" class="button_drop outline">
          </form>
```

Comment: I was looking to accept values from my HTML form. For example say Signup form

Comment: `<input type="text" id="id_FullName"   name="FullName" />` this will  work .

Comment: Thanks it worked. So it is like in ID attribute we need to have id = "id_fieldname"  & the same fieldname has to be used in forms.py/models.py whichever place you define it.

Comment: @JeevanBodas You need to pass `id=id_fieldname" as well as 'name="name_fieldname"` to your template .

Answer (score 0):

You can render the field manually.[[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)]

Here is a sample taken from the docs for a subject field

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.subject.errors }}
    {{ form.subject.label_tag }}
    {{ form.subject }}
</div>
```

Comment: I am looking to accept the values from the HTML form (say for example Signup form) rather than displaying the values on the form. The approach provided in documentation is to fetch the values & display.